# Change the order of the properties window in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Maybe this is a bit of laziness on my part.  I'm learning VB and doing examples from a book on my own and I really enjoy how the four most used properties (Name, Location, Size, and Text) are almost evenly spaced out in the Properties windows.  Using either the grouping or the a-z has about the same effect.  I frequently use the wheel to scroll through and sometimes the cursor hits a property and changes that property.  Is it possible to customize how the properties are listed so that I could put those four right next to each other?

Comment: If you mean the property window of winforms controls, you only can order them **by category** or **alphabetically**. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492146.aspx): _"Properties can be ordered by a Categorized or Alphabetical view. You can switch between these two views by using the buttons on the Properties window. In this tutorial, it's easier to find properties through the Alphabetical view."_ So maybe you like  the alphabetical view more.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I just can't be lazy then. :-)